# Matlab: Binary Linear Programming

Tags: matlab, matrix, binary, integer, mathematical-optimization

I am trying to solve some equations on Matlab using Binary Integer Programming.
I have 3 sets of equations:

1. Ma.X=1
2. Mp.X<=1
3. Mr.X<=m*

Where, Ma is a known matrix with size 5*12

X is unknown set with size 12*1

Also Mp is known matrix with size 5*12

and Mr is a known matrix with size 4*12.

1 in the equations is an unity matrix with size 5*1 in both sets(1&2)

m* is a given known matrix with size 4*1

I'm trying to use command `bintprog` but how to put 1 equality and 2 inequalities
to get values of X. Also I don't have Function `f` to insert, I just have set of equations. Given that X unknown values with values 1 or 0.

I tried this command `bintprog([],Ma,One51,Mp,One51)`
but it gives me `The problem is infeasible.` with zeros answer matrix.

Please help me to solve this on Matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct syntax for `bintprog` is `X = bintprog(f,A,b,Aeq,beq)`.

If you don't have `f` (which means you just want *any* feasible point), you can set it to `[]`. However, for the others, your syntax is slightly wrong.

I am assuming that the `+` in your constraints is actually a `*` since otherwise, the matrix algebra doesn't quite make sense.

Try this:

```
X = bintprog([],[Mp;Mr],[ones(5,1);mstar],Ma,ones(5,1))
```

If even  then it tells you that the problem is infeasible; it might as well be true that there are no `X`s that can satisfy all your constraints.

Comment: Sorry for `+` mistake, I fixed it to `*`. It still gives me no feasible solution.

Comment: @EslamSaad. It is probably true then that there is no feasible solution.